# Are there advantages of having a Japanese vs an American 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, version-differences, region-lock, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I am from India, and I am planing to order new Nintendo 3DS XL from Play-Asia. I am looking at either a Japanese version or an American version.

The Japanese version is cheaper for me, but I don't know Japanese. I'm mainly going to use it for Pokémon games (which usually have a lot of text).

So my questions are:

1. Are there any advantages or disadvantages of having a Japanese vs an American 3DS?
2. Can you change the language in Japanese games?
3. Will Indian chargers work with the US console?

Comment: "I am getting japanese version and american version." I'm assuming you meant "japanese **or** american". If not, feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not keen on Japanese, I'd recommend to focus on the USA one. Language can be changed in **some** Japanese games, but **only if English is supported.**

The vast majority of JP games only support the Japanese language. A second language only appears when the cartridge is expected on international market, and only in their versions. Most Pokemon games **do** include English as a language choice, so up to you!

The 3DS XL does not include a power adapter. If there is not one in India, you may get the one (Japanese, European, USA) and get an adaptor

Comment: Another advantage of the Japanese version: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233798/why-do-speed-runners-usually-use-the-japanese-version-of-a-game (may not apply)

Answer (score 1):

The 3DS is region-locked, so if you buy a japanese 3DS you will only be able to play imported japanese games, and if you buy a 3DS from europe you will only be able to play their games, and so on.

Being able to change the language depends on the game, I think. A lot of japanese games are only available in japanese, but some might have an option for english or other languages.

Chargers are sold independently so you will probably be able to find one more locally to fit indian power sockets.